# Visual Studio version for compiling PHP extension

Tags: php, visual-studio, apache, compilation

Which version of Visual Studio should I use for compiling PHP 5.3 and its extensions for Apache 2.2 downloaded from Apache.org?

I read somewhere that the httpd server downloaded from Apache.org is compatible only with PHP compiled with VS6. For using PHP extension compiled with VS 2008 I need to download httpd server from ApacheLounge.com. Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It is true .